# How to get customer information in magento 2

Tags: event-observer, customer, magento2-dev-beta

In my custom module I'm trying to get the `Customer, Customer Address, Product` and `Order` information through `events/observers` but it's not working. When I'm hit the **Save Button** the website is hanging.

**my code is:**

**Learning/Custom/etc/frontend/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_save_after">
        <observer name="custom_event" instance="Learning\Custom\Model\Observer" method="getCustomer" />
    </event>
    <event name="customer_address_save_commit_after">
        <observer name="custom_event" instance="Learning\Custom\Model\Observer" method="getCustomerAddress" />
    </event>
    <event name="sales_order_save_after">
        <observer name="custom_event" instance="Learning\Custom\Model\Observer" method="getOrder" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Learning/Custom/etc/adminhtml/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_commit_after">
        <observer name="custom_event" instance="Learning\Custom\Model\Observer" method="getProduct" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Learning\Custom\Model\Observer.php**

```
<?php

namespace Learning\Custom\Model;

class Observer{

    /**
     * Get the Customer Information
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function getCustomer(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       /* $customer = $observer->getCustomer();*/

        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $customer = $event->getCustomer();

        file_put_contents('customer.txt',print_r($customer,true));
    }

    /**
     * Get the Customer Address Information
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function getCustomerAddress(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /*$customerAddress = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
        $customer = $customerAddress->getCustomer();*/

        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $customerAddress = $event->getCustomerAddress();
        $customer = $customerAddress->getCustomer();

        file_put_contents('customerAddress.txt',print_r($customerAddress,true));
        file_put_contents('customer.txt',print_r($customer,true));
    }

    /**
     * Get the Order Information
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function getOrder(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

       /* $order = $observer->getOrder();*/

        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $order = $event->getOrder();

        file_put_contents('order.txt',print_r($order,true));
    }

    /**
     * Get the Product Information
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function getProduct(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        /* $product_id = $observer->getProduct()->getId();*/

        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $Product = $event->getProduct();

        file_put_contents('Product.txt',print_r($Product,true));
    }


}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have `tried to put object to  file`  and ***that is really bad idea*** .that reason the issues are creating..

Whenever,you have tried to ***print an object to  file***  and it ***was access take lot ram*** that machine is hanged up.

My suggest to **get data from object and put this value to an array the  print that array on text file**

Suppose for `sales_order_save_after`

If want to get data then use ***getData()*** for getting  in array format.

> ```
> $event = $observer->getEvent();
>   $order = $event->getOrder();
>
>  //Zend_Debug::dump($order->getData(), $label = null, $echo = true);
>  file_put_contents('order.txt',\Zend_Debug::dump($order->getData(), $label = null, $echo = true));
> ```

Comment: customer and customerAddress is working. but order and product not working, again it's hanging when i use `$order->getData()` and `$product->getData()`?

Comment: i am little lit of busy.. get back to u shortly

Comment: did you get the chance to look into above issue?

Comment: any update on this issue?

Comment: @AmitBera, How I can achieve same functionality without observer? Could you please suggest me, It would be really appreciated if you help me out this issue. I have also posted my question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173168/magento-2-create-custom-block-and-phtml-in-magento-customer-module) .