# Magento 2 create custom block and phtml in Magento_Customer module

Tags: magento2, customer-account, phtml, magento2.1.5

I want to create a new custom Block and Block phtml file same as the `Customer Index Block` for use by the customer, when the customer login the customer just clicks on the left navigation link and access the phtml file.

I have added the custom link already in the below XML file:

**app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme\Magento_Customer\layout/customer_account.xml**

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-account-myinformation-link">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">my information</argument>
        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/myinformation</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

After clicking on this link, I want to call Block to get customer data like email, name mobile, address, etc.

Please help me if anyone has created the Custom Block and Custom phtml file in the **Magento_Customer module**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to extend **Magento_Customer** by creating a new controller *customer/account/myinformation* in your module with adding configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="customer" frontName="customer">
            <module name="Magento_Customer" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Next, you can create a layout and blocks.

Add a new link to My Account:
https://webkul.com/blog/account-navigation-link-magento2/

Comment: thanks for your answer. Could you please share the complete answer here. I am still stuck at this module. I will accept and upvote you answer.

Comment: @mageDev0688 I found answer early that wrote additional information :) Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/121359/40609

Comment: thanks I have created the module, but right now it's giving 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Module Namspace/Customer

Create xml view/frontend/layout/customer_account_myinformation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>

        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="NameSpace\Customer\Block\Account\MyInformation" name="myinformation" template="account/myinformation.phtml"></block>
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

Create phtml file view/frontend/templates/account/myinformation.phtml

```
Add Your Code in phtml
```

Create Controller Controller/Account/MyInformation.php

```
    <?php

namespace Namespace\Customer\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;


/**
 * For MyInformation Controller
 */
class MyInformation extends Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;



    protected $coreRegistry;

    /**
     * Index constructor.
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,

    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface|\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->initiateCustomer();
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('My Information'));
        return $resultPage;
    }



}// end class
```

create Block Block\Account\MyInformation.php

```
<?php

namespace NameSpace\Customer\Block\Account;


use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;


class MyInformation extends Template
{


    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;



    protected $customerSession;

    protected $url;

    /**
     * Cancel constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        array $data = [],

        Session $customerSession,

    ) {


        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve current order model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        return $this->customerSession->getCustomer();
    }





}//end class
```

create routes.xml   etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="namespace_customer">
            <module name="Namespace_Customer"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Hope it will help you. Please vote us if you like our answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow bellow steps**

**Step: 1 (module.xml) app/code/Ccc/HelloWorld/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Ccc_HelloWorld" setup_version="1.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step: 2 app/code/Ccc/HelloWorld/composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "ccc/helloworld",
    "description": "Ccc HelloWorld",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "amasty/base": "*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": [
        "Commercial"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Ccc\\HelloWorld\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

**Step: 3 (routes.xml) app/code/Ccc/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
        <module name="Ccc_HelloWorld" />
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

**Step: 4 (registration.php) app/code/Ccc/HelloWorld/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Ccc_HelloWorld',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step: 5 (Index.php) app/code/Ccc/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Index.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Ccc\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    /**      * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context      */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Hello World'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**Step: 6 (HelloWorld.php) app/code/Ccc/HelloWorld/Block/HelloWorld.php**

```
<?php
namespace Ccc\HelloWorld\Block;

class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout()
    { 
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
}
```

**Step: 7 (helloworld_index_index.xml) app/code/Ccc/HelloWorld/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Ccc\HelloWorld\Block\HelloWorld" name="helloworld" template="helloworld.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Step: 8 (helloworld.phtml) app/code/Ccc/HelloWorld/view/frontend/templates/helloworld.phtml**

```
<?php 
echo 'Successful! This is a simple module in Magento 2.0';
?>
```

**Step: 9 Execute the commands**

```
bin/magento module:enable Ccc_HelloWorld
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```